# Why can std:set (with a single colon) compile?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I accidentally wrote

```
std::set<string> keys;
```

as:

```
std:set<string> keys;
```

but weirdly enough, Visual Studio 2013 still compiles.

Why does this happen?

Actually `keys` is not only defined, but later used as a set of strings, such as

```
if(keys.find(keystr)==keys.end()){
    keys.insert(keystr);
    toret.push_back(tempv);
}
```

Comment: `std:` is interpreted as a `label` for a `goto`. see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto

Answer (score 104, accepted):

At block scope, an identifier followed by a single colon introduces a label. Thus, your statement is equivalent to:

```
set<string> keys;
```

except that it bears the label `std` and can be jumped to by the statement `goto std;`.

For some reason, the name `set` is known to the compiler---perhaps you did `using namespace std;`, or `using std::set;`, or something like that, or perhaps you defined your own `set` type somewhere.

Comment: This is another reason to avoid `using namespace std;` and `using std::set;`

Comment: There are good arguments to be made against `using namespace std`/`using std::set`, but I'm not sure this is one of them... the main argument is usually that namespaces are there to prevent collisions, but if there is a non-std 'set' to collide with, then `std: set<...>` would probably be valid. Common practice is to limit any such using declarations to another namespace/function, but this problem could just as easily happen in that scope. I would sooner expect a typo to creep in rewriting `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`, etc. ad nauseum than this label typo (the first I've seen like it.)

Answer (score 11):

In the second case, std is a label.  It is the same as spelling default incorrectly in a case statement.